# Android CalendarView set an event

Tags: android, calendarview

im using CalendarView and im trying to set an event on the calendar user.
the app opens the defualt calendar phones with Intent and there the user set the time of the event, headline and location.
my only problem is that i dont know how to use it.
should i use OnDateChangeListener or just Onclick? 
what im trying to do is to get the parameters that the user sets and open event on his defualt calendar.

**I'm using this code**

```
    public void addEvent(String title,String location, long begin, long end) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, begin)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, end);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Also i would like to know what "long begin" and "long end" means? 
It is user input?

I hope i was clear enought.

Comment: its start and end time in long(ms) for event.

Comment: Do you know how do i get those inputs from the user?

Comment: For that you have to create UI, to get start time and end time.

Use timepicker

Answer (score 0):

You can add the event using the code below

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

Here begin time and end time are the start and end time of the reminders you are setting for the event.

Add these permissions too in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

Comment: For some reason i cant add  **Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();** should i import something?

Comment: It comes with the java.lang.Object import. You don't have to add any outside library.

Comment: Ok i understand, but still that code line is not working. **Calendar cal = new Calendar();** works

Comment: It does not find that method **getInstance();**  i write *Calendar cal = Calendar.** and thats it. it doesn't give me the option of that method

Comment: You must have imported some other calendar. Check your imports.

Comment: I have import **import android.provider.CalendarContract;** and **import android.widget.CalendarView;**

Comment: Please remove all that imports and see.